# Print data from mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

In a kiosk like application, I'm trying to print at a set interval (my case 60 secs) the last 60 secs of inserted records in a mysql database.

**With the code below is there any possibility from a ajax refresh delay or anything to omit printing a record?** 
If it is , is there anything I can do to avoid that?

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
@media print {
tr.page-break {
    display: block;
    page-break-before: always;
}
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function getData(){
           $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'data.php',
                success: function(data){
                    $('#output').html(data);

                             function isEmpty( el ){
          return !$.trim(el.html())
      }
      if (!isEmpty($('#output'))) {
           window.print();
      }                         
                }
            });
        }

        getData();
        setInterval(function () { getData();  }, 60000);  // it will refresh your data every 1 sec

    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the `data.php` :

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "testdb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "select * from orders where time > date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute) ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data1 =$row["id"];
        $data2= $row["product"];
        $data3= $row["details"];
        echo "<tr class='page-break'>";
        echo "<td>" . $data1  . "</<td>";
        echo "<td>" . $data2  . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $data3  . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} 
$conn->close();

?>
```

The code is just for testing not production so don't mind the php security issues (sql injection and so). But I would greatly appreciate if you could improve in any way the javascript part.

**Is there any better solution than this to print the last 60 secs records in a mysql database?**

Comment: I'd use Ajax. Also I'd record the previous upper limit of the range so that then i can use it to define the new range as previuos_upper_limit+60secs instead of using now+60secs

Comment: Can you elaborate on the upper_limit please? How should I record it? In mysql or is there any other way?

Comment: in your query: lower_limit=now-60secs and upper limit=now. What i say is to change it to lower_limit=[upper_limit from previous run of the query] and upper_limit = lower_limit+60secs. You can do it with Ajax easily (without reloading the whole page)

Comment: How do I set the lower_limit as upper_limit from a previous run? Do I need to store the last time in the database? Can you please post the query?

Comment: as I was saying this works better if you use ajax (without reloading the page) but if you reload the page you need to make it persistent using the db. Consider that ajax is the fastest way and avoid asincronicity between current time and the interval you are querying

Comment: I edited my question, I added ajax. Can you please provide some example of how to record the previous_upper_limit?

Comment: You could send the data rows found as a JSON array, and build the table in javascript. Then, order the results by time not by id, so you can take the last one provided as the limit for the next query using `>`

Comment: After I take the last time from the json array how can I insert it back into sa sql query?

Comment: You can pass it in the data field of the ajax call, if it is set already

Comment: How can I pass it from the json array to the data field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @Adder's code I ended up with this:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $.ajax({ // Get lastID
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'lastid.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    'success': function (data) {
                        callback(data);
                    }
                });
                var return_last;
                function callback(response) {
                    return_last = response;
                    var lastID = return_last.id;




                    function getData() {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'GET',
                            url: 'data.php',
                            data: {lastID: lastID},
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (data) {
                                lastID = data[0].id;
                                console.log(lastID);
                                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                                    var $tr = $('<tr class="page-break">').append(
                                            $('<td>').text(item.id),
                                            $('<td>').text(item.name),
                                            $('<td>').text(item.details)
                                            ).appendTo('#output');
                                });

                                function isEmpty(el) {
                                    return !$.trim(el.html());
                                }
                                if (!isEmpty($('#output'))) {
                                    window.print();
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    }

                    getData();


                    setInterval(function () {
                        $("tr").addClass("no-print");
                        getData();
                    }, 60000);  // it will refresh your data every 1 minute
                }
            });
        </script>
```

And the sql

```
$lastID = $_GET['lastID'];
$sql = "select * from orders where id > ".$lastID." ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$dataArray = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $dataArray[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($dataArray);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have written the following code as an example for using a `lastTime` variable to use in the SQL query, in order for the SQL query to continue where the last query ended.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var lastTime = 0;
      function getData(){
           $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'data.php',
                data: {lastTime: lastTime},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    for(var i = 0; i<data.length; ++i) {
                        var row = data[i];
                        printRow('#output', row);
                        lastTime = row.time;    
                    }

                }
            });
        }

        function printRow(where, row) {
            //build html
            var html = '';
            html+= '<div class="row">';
            ... // TODO
            html+= '</div>';
            $(where).append(html);
        }

        getData();
        setInterval(function () { getData();  }, 60000);  // it will refresh your data every 1 minute

    });
```

Comment: I added this in `data.php` `$sql = "select * from orders where id > ".$lastTime." ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$dataArray = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $dataArray[] = $row;
    }
 
 echo json_encode($dataArray);

}`  but I get nothing in the index.php file

Comment: use either `select * from orders where time > ".$lastTime." ORDER BY time ASC` or use the id everywhere:  `select * from orders where id > ".$lastId." ORDER BY id ASC`

Comment: A question, what format or data type does the field `time` have?

Comment: `datetime` but I can change it if you think something else is better

Comment: If I use my original query `select * from orders where time > date_sub(now(), interval 1 minute) ORDER BY id DESC` and your jquery code , every 60 secs I get  all the results in the last minute but without content . If I have 3 results in the last minute I get 3 empty `<div class="row"></div>`

Comment: If I use your query I get nothing in html

Comment: Can you put the value of lastTime in single quotes? What did you replace the TODO part with?

Comment: If you mean in the sql query, yes I tried, same issue. Do you have 1min to chat please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176343/discussion-between-adder-and-victordb).